# EF Core - Gloabl Filter at runtime

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to apply a global filter to my entities. I have implemented this in OnModelCreating, where the filter is done on the basis of the correctly logged in user. Since OnModelCreating is only invoked once, I have to be sure that the filters applied on the DbSets types are updated correctly if some properties of my logged in user change at runtime. How can I invoke OnModelCreating on demand? Or, is there any other workaround with no performance losses due for example to removing the EF cache on the model builder?

Query filter is applied by the following extension method: https://gist.github.com/alirizaadiyahsi/bede89ba3d301f151a13bc58908a61ac

My CustomDbContext exposes a delegate invoked from within the OnModelCreating method and that delegate is initialized by my access layer business class.

Here a sample code:

```
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

            // Invoke delegate where my BusinessAccessLayer will perform filter operations
            this.OnModelCreatingHandler?.Invoke(modelBuilder);
        }

// My Business logic

private MyLoggedUser { get; private set; }

void OnModelCreatingHandlerMethod(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                if (typeof(IEntity).IsAssignableFrom(entityType.ClrType))
                    modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).AddQueryFilter<IEntity>(e => e.SomeProperty > MyLoggedUser.SomeValue);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have already dig one day in EF Core sources did not found solution. Anyway you can create new class dynamically derived from your context and apply filters in it's `OnModelCreating` method.

Comment: Suppose you have an `ISoftDelete `interface, and you implement this interface on the class that you want to implement global filtering. Do you mean that its `IsDeleted `property changes during runtime? That will not affect your global filter.

Comment: I'm forced to insert business logic within MyDbContext cos it's not possible, for instance, invoke a delegate or function to apply my custom filter. Only where clause within onModelCreating is supported.